# How to hide Weblogic WLDF Console Extension Tab from Weblogic adinn console?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I use Weblogic 12.1.3, when logged to admin server I see a tab with label "WLDF Console Extension" when choosing it, I get this message

"The WLDF Console Extension, which provided visual tools to display diagnostic information in this domain, has been replaced in this release by new integrated Monitoring Dashboard and Request Performance tools. For more information on these updates, please consult the online help and release notes for this release..."
How to hide this uselss tab, I have another installtion at work with the same version does not have this tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the WLDF extension is not installed by default so someone must have put it there and/or turned it on. To remove it there are 2 options:

- Navigate to `<domain dir>/console-ext` and remove the `diagnostics-console-extension.jar` file. Restart your admin server.
- Click the perferences link at the top of the admin console, click the Extensions tab, find the `diagnostics-console-extension` and disable it

If you ever need it back you can re-enable it or copy it back into your domain directory from the `WL_HOME\server\lib\console-ext` folder